# Sheets to GCal Apps Script Trouble Shooting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have the below code to take a list of events in a Google Sheet and schedule them into a Google Calendar.

```
function addEvents(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var calId = ss.getRange("C4").getValue();
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calId);
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  
  var data = ss.getRange("B9:F" + lr).getValues();

  for(var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){ 
    
    cal.createEvent(data[i][0], data[i][1], data[i][2], {location: data[i][3], description: data[i][4]});

  }


}
```

I've used this script before with no issues, but now I'm getting the following error message and can't for the life of me figure out what is going on:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null

I ultimately would like to add an if statement to this code that grabs the newly created Event ID and puts it in the last column of the data on the sheet, and I would like to be asking for help with that, but at this point I just need step one to work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why is that so difficult? cal must be null. Check the value in C4.  And make sure that you are on the correct sheet/tab since you did not actually specify the sheet/tab

Comment: Can you provide a Sheets file that reproduces this behavior? As `Cooper` mentioned above, most likely the issue is the value of C4 not being a valid calendar ID, therefore `getCalendarById()` returns null since it was not able to retrieve a calendar that the authenticated user has access with that ID.